# Local Content different from Remote Content

Tags: database, content, localhost, remote

## Problem Description

I am developing a project using Wordpress as a CMS for a web page of a Scientific Research Group to Publish Information, News, Publications and Projects of the Scientific Group.

I began to develop the whole basic structure of the pages locally through the MAMP application and yesterday tried to migrate everything to my accommodation at GoDaddy.

## What I Did

Initially had some migration issues, I called them, they helped me in some way, but not all of all my problems.

It turns out that at the beginning I did the following:

1) Migrate all for Local Environment files for Remote for FileZilla FTP;

2) Set the file wp-config.php;

3) Export the Local Environmental Database by myPHPAdmin;

4) Import the Remote Environment Database through myPHPAdmin;

At the end of all this encounter that the contents of the Remote Environment is enrrado and I did the Technical GoDaddy do not know why.

## My Questions

a) Will there be any inconsistency with regard to versions used in place over the remote?

b) The use of plugins can cause this behavior?

c) Does the database should not be Exported in its entirety?

If case you happened the same please describe your situation and how to solve.

## Some Information

Here I will short describe some important information to understand my problem, with the main difference in Homepage between both environments.

### Local Environment Screenshots

[image]

As you can observe the content is different as you watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solve my problem by configuring the all content by default.

However I did the same on another example and I came alive with zero configuration to be done, I still don't understand.

### The Answers

a) There is no inconsistency with regard to versions used in place over the remote at that time;

b) The use of Plugins did cause the behavior, but technically I don't exactly why;

c) The Database **MUST** be **Exported** (Local) and **Imported** (Remote);